# Unable to use Node-Red with token verification to request kubernetesAPI

Tags: kubernetes, node-red, bearer-token

The Node-Red flow is as follows：
[image]

Related attributes：
[image]

I have appended the Token string, why can’t I get a GET request?
**The error is as follows：**
*"Error: unable to verify the first certificate : [https://192.168.58.160:6443/api/v1/namespaces/nodes/"](https://192.168.58.160:6443/api/v1/namespaces/nodes/%22)*

Comment: try just http, if you go for https, then certificate is a must

Answer (score 2):

If you enable SSL/TLS and create a SSL/TLS configuration for the connection you can either supply a CA certificate or disable Certificate verification.

[image]